# ASP.NET MVC and Payement gateway

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

I am working on a hotel reservation module.  This is an ASP.NET MVC application.  I have a requirement of building a workflow integrating with payment gateway. When customer reserve the facilitates in the hotel with valid debit/credit card, the amount has to be blocked against their card, and upon cancellation, the reservation fees has to be charged and cancel the reservation.  Can anyone suggest a suitable and affordable payment gateway and their product that support my requirement?

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [Sage Pay Go](http://www.sagepay.com/online-payments) (formerly known as Protx I believe). I'm not sure about the 'blocking' feature you talk about, but you could definitely put a transaction through just to see if they had sufficient funds without actually charging for it. Maybe it had the blocking function you talk about, but I can't remember.

What I do remember though was how easy it was to use. They provide a .dll with a nicely thought out object model. It was very straight forward to integrate with my web app.

The company I was working for at the time were tight with money so couldn't have been too expensive.